# Java table cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable, instance

I have the following classes

**class Parsing**

```
class Parsing {
  private ClassWithTable c = new ClassWithTable();

  public void doAction(){
    parseRowData();
    c.initComponents();
  }

  private void parseRowData(){
    Object[][] rowData = new Object[3][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        rowData[i][0] = "A string";
        rowData[i][1] = null;
    }
    c.setRowData(rowData);
  }
}
```

**class ClassWithTable**

```
class ClassWithTable {
  private JTable table;
  private Object[][]rowData;
  private final String[] colNames = new String[]{null,null};

  public void initComponents() {
    table = new JTable(getRowData(),colNames); //in this line I get the exception
    System.out.println(table.getValueAt(1, 1));
  }

  public void setRowData(Object[][]rowData){this.rowData = rowData;}
  private Object[][] getRowData(){return this.rowData;}  
  public JTable getTable(){return table;}
}
```

**class JTableInstantiation**

```
public class JTableInstantiation {
  public static void main (String[] af){
    ClassWithTable c = new ClassWithTable();
    Parsing p = new Parsing();
    p.doAction();

  }
}
```

When I run it, I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I figured out that the table inside `ClassWithTable` cannot be instantiated, despite the fact that `rowData` take all right values. Could you please explain to me why is this happening? What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Exception table:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.JTable$1.getColumnName(JTable.java:685)
at javax.swing.JTable.addColumn(JTable.java:2801)
at javax.swing.JTable.createDefaultColumnsFromModel(JTable.java:1287)
at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4386)
at javax.swing.JTable.setModel(JTable.java:3688)
at javax.swing.JTable.<init>(JTable.java:632)
at javax.swing.JTable.<init>(JTable.java:573)
at javax.swing.JTable.<init>(JTable.java:684)
at drafts.ClassWithTable.initComponents(JTableInstantiation.java:28)
at drafts.Parsing.doAction(JTableInstantiation.java:10)
at drafts.JTableInstantiation.main(JTableInstantiation.java:41)
```

Comment: If you ever have a NPE (NullPointerException) question, please please please indicate which line throws it.

Comment: ok I am adding it. See Edit

Comment: Again, you need to show us the line. Which line is `JTableInstantiation.java:28`? The stacktrace is given to you for a reason, to help you debug. Please help us help you.

Comment: Yes, you've right. I commented the line

Answer (score 3):

Keep track of your fields. You have two `ClassWithTable` objects.

#### class JTableInstantiation

```
ClassWithTable vEntity = new ClassWithTable();
```

You have vEntity here. Then you do:

```
  Parsing p = new Parsing();
  p.doAction();
```

Look at what's inside `Parsing`

```
private ClassWithTable c = new ClassWithTable();
```

You haven't done anything with `vEntity` at all. You need to either assign `vEntity` the value of `p.getClassWithTable()` or pass `vEntity` to `p`.

Comment: I corrected the fields. You may see the edit

Comment: couldn't I remove vEntity from JTableInstantiation, move println inside Parsing#parseRowData and call p.doAction() inside main to print table?

Comment: @VassilisDe Yes. It depends ultimately on what you want to do with your method. If Parsing is the only one that is responsible for the Table, then you can keep it in there as a field.

Comment: Well I did this pretty much like my updated question. Like you said, `Parsing` is the only class that is responsible for the Table, but still I get that exception...

Comment: @VassilisDe Try `new String[]{"A","B"};` for column names. I believe it also needs actual values for the names.

Comment: you are genious!!!! That was the problem...everything works!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Parsing {
  private ClassWithTable c = new ClassWithTable();

  public void doAction(){
    parseRowData();
    c.initComponents();
    System.out.println(c.getTable().getValueAt(1, 1));
  }

  private void parseRowData(){
    Object[][] rowData = new Object[3][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        rowData[i][0] = "A string";
        rowData[i][1] = null;
    }
    c.setRowData(rowData);
  }
}

class ClassWithTable {
  private JTable table;
  private Object[][]rowData;
  private final String[] colNames = new String[]{"A","B"}; // CHANGED nulls for Strings

  public void initComponents() {
    table = new JTable(getRowData(),colNames); //in this line I get the exception
    System.out.println(table.getValueAt(1, 1));
  }

  public void setRowData(Object[][]rowData){this.rowData = rowData;}
  private Object[][] getRowData(){return this.rowData;}  
  public JTable getTable(){return table;}
}
public class JTableInstantiation {
  public static void main (String[] af){
    Parsing p = new Parsing();
    p.doAction();
  }
}
```

Comment: couldn't I just move println inside Parsing#parseRowData and call `p.doAction()` to print table? initComponents() is called, but not inside `main()`

Comment: @Vassilis De now I see you are instatiating twice ClassWithTable. I'll uodate my answer.

Comment: I have it EXACTLY the way you wrote it, but I'm still getting the same exeption

Comment: The line that is giving the NPE in Jtable is `public String getColumnName(int column) { return columnNames[column].toString(); }` . Need to use notNull names for columns.